# When does ConvertBack method get called?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, ivalueconverter

I know that when data is about to be displayed, `Convert()` method is called to convert the data and the converted data is displayed instead.

I'm wondering when `ConvertBack()` method gets called? What is its purpose?

I've a `DataGrid` whose `ItemSource` is binded to some collection, and I've implemented `IValueConverter` for one property of items in the collection. When I make `IsReadOnly="True"` (in the *DataGrid*), then `ConvertBack` method is called if I double-click on the cell (for which `IValueConverter` is implemented) and then change the focus. But when I make `IsReadOnly="False"`, then `ConvertBack` method is never called, no matter what I do with the `DataGrid` and its cells.

Please explain this behavior of `DataGrid` cells and `ConvertBack` method of `IValueConverter`.

Comment: It is called when the binding mode is TwoWay (default mode for TextBox.Text and probably for CheckBox.IsChecked). If you set OneWay explicitly , the method will not be called, I think.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. If I bind directly to a `DataTable` the source gets updated on `CellEditEnding`. If I bind to a different kind of object and use a converter in the binding to convert it to a `DataTable` on the fly `ConvertBack` never gets called. Meaning user edits don't get propagated to the source. I'm wondering if I need to derive my own `DataTable`and add some kind of notification logic to it. Will post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The data binding engine calls this method when it propagates a value from the binding target to the binding source."

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback.aspx)

you should post your binding for your cell with the valueconverter

Comment: So if you don't want it to propagate back to the source, you make the binding Mode=OneWay?